# Easy way to repair windows with broken sash cords

Tags: windows

I have about a dozen double-hung windows that have broken sash cords. I know how to repair sash cords, but it is tedious work.

Is there any alternative, "quick and easy" way to repair the windows such that they can be opened again, at least partly? I'm envisioning, for instance, some kind of hardware that can be installed in the window frame to hold the windows open at fixed positions, then retracted to allow them to close again -- essentially, a user-friendly variation on driving a screw into the frame to hold the window up, then unscrewing it when you want to close the window.

If there is a way to tie broken sash cords back together, that would work, too. Most of my sash cords are still in place, but are cut.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can (if you can get them in your country) use the Simplex sash window hinges. These are used in Scotland to allow windows on tall tenement buildins to open inwards for cleaning.

http://www.traditionalhardwaredirect.com/windowfittingproducts/simplexsystem.html

https://www.reddiseals.com/product-category/sash-window/simplex-system/

You would use a 'H' style hinge on the frame and a locating screw on the face of the sash. Slide the sash up above the hinge, fold out the hinge, then lower the sash so the locating screw engages with the hinge and supports the weight of the sash.

The system is demonstrated at

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVuzskoTTt4

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a broken/cut sash cord, is that the sash wants to drop to the bottom (d'uh).  This is fine for the lower sash (where "bottom" is "closed"), but not so great for the upper sash.

A "quick and easy" temporary solution would be to drive a screw to hold the top sash up, and then provide a stick to hold the lower sash open.  This will make the window (mostly) weathertight while you take the time to solve all the other problems in the property.